# Disabling scrolling while dragging on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a list of items that can be re-sorted. I have set it up on mobile where the item is to begin being moved after a long-hold, followed by a drag to re-position it.

It works fine when only a few items are present, but once enough appear to allow the `div` to scroll (only the `div` containing the `ul` scrolls, not the whole page), I can no longer re-position items as dragging causes a scroll.

I have tried using `.preventDefault()` on `touchmove`, but it does not appear to have an effect.

Basically, I have this:

```
$(document).on('touchmove mousemove', e => {
  // check to make sure we're holding something
  // if not, just return

  e.preventDefault()
  // this stops the text from being highlighted,
  // but does not stop scrolling

  // report the mouse/touch position to the actual move function.
})
```

Most solutions say that using `preventDefault()` stops it, but that does not appear to be the case.

What can I do here?

Edit: I have tried manipulating the `overflow` property, but that prevents the div from being programmatically scrolled as well, which it needs to do.

Comment: you could try to manipulate the overflow style property

Comment: @Sombriks I tried this, but that seems to completely stop any access to elements outside the div. I need it to scroll when the held item approaches the top/bottom (which I can handle programmatically), but the overflow stops that. Edited original question to mention that.

Comment: in that case, i'm assuming mousemove events are being "ate" by scroll events. if so, maybe a drop event might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop

Answer (score 0):

try to prevent scroll:

```
$('div').on('scroll', function(e) {e.preventDefault()});
```

Comment: Nothing. This doesn't appear to stop the scrolling.

Comment: Probably div and body are both scrolling? Could you please add a code example in codepen or smth?